# ¿Por qué no identifica el modulo tkinter en VScode?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, vscode

Utilizo Ubuntu y VScode .
Este es el codigo e tratad con otros comandos de otras versiones pero me sigue dando el mismo error principalmente:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

master = tk.Tk()

def callback1():
    print ("Click en el boton de tkinter")

def callback2():
    print ("Click en el boton de ttk")

boton1 = tk.Button(master, text="Tkinter", command=callback1)
boton2 = ttk.Button(master, text="ttk", command=callback2)
boton1.pack()
boton2.pack()

master.mainloop()
```

Y este es el error que me da al correr:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/diego/eclipse-workspace/Python/cosas chungas/Ventanas.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tkinter as tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La salida de error te está dando la solución, está diciendo que NO tienes instalado el módulo tkinter.
Observa tu ultima linea de error:  **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'**

Para usarlo debes instalarlo tal como te comenta @Angel. tkinter no viene "de serie" con el interprete de Python.

Por añadir algo sobre Ubuntu... desde la terminal es conveniente que antes de instalar el múdulo pongas al día tu sistema, así:

sudo apt-get update -y

Y luego ya instalas el módulo, así
sudo apt-get install -y python3-tk

(Asumo que estás en un Ubuntu 18 o superior)
Salud

Comment: Muchas gracias @DoctorChocolate

Answer (score 1):

Puede ser que tengas que instalarlo de esta forma:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

[Fuente (en inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905540/importerror-no-module-named-tkinter)

[Documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html)